# Count only rows meeting case-sensitive criteria and if adjacent row is not blank

Tags: excel

I'm trying to count cells within column A of Sheet 1 containing a case-sensitive data and if column B in same sheet is not blank. Currently, I'm able to count the case-sensitive cells using the formula below:

```
=IFERROR(IF($C2="","",COUNT(INDEX(FIND("mMMm",Sheet1!$A:$A),))),"-")
```

Next criteria to incorporate (besides the one above) would be to count only the values if its adjacent cell in column B is not blank. So far, I've tried incorporating a `MATCH(<>"",Sheet1!B:B,0)*` and an IF statement to achieve this, but to no avail. I also tried returning it as an array formula, but still nothing. May I ask for your guidance on this. I'm not sure if what I've done are actually on track to what I want to do, but I would love to know and learn a function that does the job. Thanks!

Here's some sample data to better grasp this concern:

```
Column A       Column B
12mMMmqq          1
sdmMmMqqq         1
ssmMMmree         1
wemMMmm12
mMMm11111
mMmMmM1121        1
```

So in the above sample data, my current formula would return a count of 4 (cells containing case-sensitive "mMMm"). However, what I wish to achieve is a count of 2 (those meeting the previous criteria and with a non-blank cell adjacent to it).

Thanks!

Comment: This can be done very easily with VBA. Would you like to try it out? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

From your explanation in the comments, use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDIRECT(C1&"!F2:F7")<>""),--(ISNUMBER(FIND("mMMm",INDIRECT(C1&"!A2:A7")))))
```

This assumes C2 in current sheet has the sheet name e.g. Sheet1. And that column A and column F of that sheet are those of interest. You would adjust the ranges ensuring they are the same length

---

You can use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B7<>""),--(ISNUMBER(FIND("mMMm",A2:A7,1))))
```

If in another sheet then add the sheet name in front of the range e.g.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B7<>""),--(ISNUMBER(FIND("mMMm",Sheet1!A2:A7,1))))
```

If wanting blanks in col B then use `=""`

Same sheet example:

[image: Same sheet]

Notes:

`Find`, unlike `Search` is case sensitive.

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` to handle the two arrays. Array 1 is a boolean array of column B `<> ""`, array 2 is column A where Find has found "mMMm" and therefore returned a number. This is wrapped in `ISNUMBER` generating a boolean array.

Both boolean arrays are converted to their respective `1` or `0` using `--`.

---

Comment: HI @QHarr ! I tried using the second formula you mentioned since I was trying to link the formula in another sheet. I was likewise using INDIRECT to link the sheet name to the formula. What I came up, after editing your formula, is the following: 
`=IFERROR(IF($C2="","",SUMPRODUCT(--(INDIRECT("'"&$C2&"'!$F:$F")<>""),--(ISNUMBER(FIND(D$1,INDIRECT("'"&$C2&"'!$A$A"),1))))),"-")`
However, this is returning an error. C2 contains the sheet's name, F:F in that sheet contains the items that should not be blank, and A:A contains the data where we need to find the value in D1. Help please, thanks!

Comment: Basically, in the sample data that I attached compared to my actual data, column A in sheet 1 is column A of the sheet name in cell C2. Likewise, column B in the sample data is column F of the sheet name in cell C2. I'm still trying to look at how this caused an error. I'll try to provide insights later. :)

Comment: I have added an edit. This assumes C2 in current sheet has the sheet name e.g. Sheet1. And that column A and column F of that sheet are those of interest. You would adjust the ranges ensuring they are the same length.

Comment: It seems there was a referencing error on my part. I missed to include the ':' character between A2:A7. I wouldn't have solved this concern without your help. Btw, I think that's supposed to be C2, not C1, on your edited formula. Thanks! :)